# how to import in format CSV chars as ñ, Ã in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, encoding

i have a problem with to import this format CSV file by your encoding

my query is:

\copy tablename from " path of the file.csv" DELIMITERS ';' CSV

OR

\copy tablename from " path of the file.csv" DELIMITERS ';' CSV header encoding 'UTF8'

OR

\copy tablename from " path of the file.csv" DELIMITERS ';' CSV header encoding 'WIN1252'

but, doesn´t insert the file data because it has an error

"error: character to byte 0x8d sequence encoding UTF8" OR
"error: character to byte 0x8d sequence encoding WIN1252"

these errors output are because I have chars Ñ,Ã and other

what type of encoding should I use?

Comment: Open yout cvs file and see what type of encoding is, you could see that with, for example, notepad++ ...

Answer (score 11):

I resolved the problem was to place the latin1 encoding

so: \copy tablename(column1, colum2.. columnN) FROM 'path_file.csv' DELIMITER ';' NULL AS ' ' CSV header encoding 'latin1';

Comment: Despite `0x8d` not corresponding to any actual character in [latin1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout). Maybe the real problem is that your file contains crap.